# Android java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: byteCount

Tags: java, android, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I get random error (not all connection) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: byteCount < 0: -291674 from this code

```
URL connurl = new URL(newUrl);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) connurl.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android");
conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
if (finish != 0L)
    conn.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + finish + "-" + size);
conn.connect();
int getResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
String getContenttype = conn.getContentType();
int contentLenght = conn.getContentLength();
if (!StringUtils.startsWith(String.valueOf(getResponseCode), "20")) {
}
else if(StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(getContenttype, "text/html")) {
}
else if(contentLenght < (size-finish)) {
}
else {
    ReadableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(conn.getInputStream()); 
    accessFile = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "rwd");
    accessFile.seek(finish);
    fileStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath, true);
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    byte[] data;
    int temp;
    while ((temp = channel.read(buffer)) > 0) { <-- error in this line
    }
```

Error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: byteCount < 0: -1647333
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:46)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource.read(HttpConnection.java:418)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:349)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$InputStreamChannel.read(Channels.java:306)
```

How to fix it?
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you are getting `200` response?

Comment: How do you initialize your `conn` variable?

Comment: it is randomly error, not all connection.
conn and http code checked at the top in this code

if (!StringUtils.startsWith(String.valueOf(getResponseCode), "20")) {

Comment: The problem is certainly because of the `Range` header. How do you initialize `finish` and `size`?

Comment: hi @user13, _finish_ is filesize already saved, _size_ is filesize, dont worry about _finish_ and _size_, existing code that checks before download file. if I write everything, it will take a lot of places.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same crash from just one user.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably linked to that issue: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3104

As suggested, consider using `okhttp-urlconnection` like:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new OkUrlFactory(okHttpClient));
```